# APIENTRY macro error

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I am trying to create a callback function for opengl debugging, following the example code from OpenGL superbible, i created the function -

```
static void APIENTRY simple_print_callback(GLenum source,
GLenum type,
GLuint id,
GLenum severity,
GLsizei length,
const GLchar* message,
void * userParam)
{
     printf("Debug message with source 0x%04X, type 0x%04X, "
     "id %u, severity 0x%0X, ’%s’\n",
     source, type, id, severity, message);
}
```

but while compiling i am getting the error

```
error: expected initializer before 'simple_print_callback'
```

My program runs fine without a debug context, so an error there is not likely.

I am running this on ubuntu 64 bit and i have included the following headers -

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

Comment: commenting the function (only the shown part) makes the error go away

Answer (score 2):

APIENTRY is a macro used in Microsoft Windows to set the calling convention of exported functions. In Linux this is not necessary. APIENTRY is defined in the `windows.h` header, but nowhere in Linux.

So you should put this at the very beginning of your source file:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#define APIENTRY
#endif
```

Comment: This AFAIK is already defined in the glew.h which I have included, which is why (i think) i do not get an APIENTRY undefined error

Comment: @Rishabh: The error is consistent with what datenwolf is describing, because the compiler seems to think APIENTRY is a function name. Are you including glew.h _before_ your callback definition (in the same file)? Also, one possible way to know is to `#define APIENTRY something_else` to try to verify that the compiler indeeds picks up the other definition (it would complain about redefinition unless the #define is guarded)

Comment: I get the same error as OP and none of your answers helps.

Comment: Ok I found my own mistake: My CMakeLists.txt contained `target_compile_definitions(... WIN32)` without a guard if the host is even a `WIN32` host. Fixed it by guarding it in a `if(WIN32)` in CMake.